# jquery UI resizable with multiple alsoResize

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having some dificulties with the following. I have an object that is resizable. The code looks as following:

```
var alsoresizablevar1;
var alsoresizablevar2;

object.resizable({
    handles: {se: object.find(".resize")},
    alsoResize: alsoresizablevar1, alsoresizablevar2
});
```

How can i add the 2 variables to the alsoResize option so they are resized together wit the original object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an eventlistener for the resizing element and resize alsoresizablevar1 & alsoresizablevar2.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better handle resizable.stop event and resize related objects manually based on the changed size of the original object. For example, I have implemented it in a simple project to resize page's sections manually by drag-and-drop.

```
$("#selector").resizable(
    {
        stop: function (e, ui)
        {
            var changedHeight = ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height;
            var changedWidth = ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width;

                    // update related objects' size based on above values.
        }
    });
```